# Buy mobile data in Morocco with Inwi SIM card

Tags: cellphones, morocco, phone-networks

I've bought a standard 30DH Inwi SIM card. I recharged it online for 200DH to have more mobile data. That data ended very soon but I still have all my calling credit. Is it possible to use this credit to buy extra data packs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is "no". 
I found out at an inwi kiosk.